# How to pickle a namespace in python

Tags: python, pickle

Is there a way to save and load an entire namespace using pickle allowing me to perform something like this:

```
import pickle
import numpy as np
a = 1
# other arbitrary code
pickle.dump(namespace,open('my_namespace.p','wb')
```

Allowing to open a new python prompt and performing the following code:

```
import pickle
namespace.update(pickle.load(open('my_namespace.p','rb'))
print(np.array(a)+1)
>>2
# using the rest of the namespace
```

Comment: This would be unlikely to work well, as your namespace could all too easily contain non-pickleable objects.  There is an extended pickle replacement called dill (https://pypi.org/project/dill/) that lists "save and load python interpreter sessions" as one of its features, although I have no experience with it.

Comment: What do you mean by `namespace`?

Comment: I am wondering what you are trying to achieve here? Why do you want to pickle the whole modules (unless I am mistaken there is no such a concept as namespace in Python)?

Comment: The idea is to be able to save a certain state of the code with all the variables and imports in order to enter and reenter the same state perform experiments. Also just wanted to know more about the python environment.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to 'freeze' a particular code version of the modules you use I suggest taking a look at [Python Virtual Environment (venv)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html). Otherwise, as jasonharper suggested - it is very unlikely to work well (particularly with modules like `NumPy` which are complex amalgamates of Python code and binary libraries).

`venv` would help you deal with that particular problem too.

Answer (score 0):

I think that I get the question.  You want to be able to restore all variables and interact with a shell in a different interpreter or at a different time.  The easiest way to do this is probably to use a notebook like jupyter or ipython.  These allow you to save all commands run and reconstitute them.  Sorry for it not being a direct answer, but I think it may "equivalently accomplish" what you specified.